# TSQL - Dynamic query to retrieve the value of given xml element using provided XPATH

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to write a SP in SQL Server 2008 where if the input is a valid XML and a XPATH i want to retrieve the value of that XPATH:

For example if i have:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <genRetrieve xmlns:v1="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
                <checkRetrieve>
                    <party>
                        <user>
                            <first>JOHN</first>
                            <last>SMITH</last>
                        </user>
                        <media />
                    </party>
                </checkRetrieve>
            </genRetrieve>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

And the XPATH is :

```
    /*[local-name() = "Envelope"][1]/*[local-name() = "Body"][1]/genRetrieve[1]/checkRetrieve[1]/party[1]/user[1]/first[1]
```

I need to grab "JOHN" and return it.

I tried the below

```
    DECLARE @xml xml,
            @xpath nvarchar(max),
            @output nvarchar(100),
            @query nvarchar(max)

    SET @xml = @userINPUT
    SET xpath = '/*[local-name() = "Envelope"][1]/*[local-name() = "Body"][1]/genRetrieve[1]/checkRetrieve[1]/party[1]/user[1]/first[1]' +  '/text()'
    SET @output = ''    
    select @output = @xml.query('sql:variable("@xpath")')
```

But instead of the value i just get the full XPATH string i passed as argument in return. I also tried dynamic query:

```
    SET @query = 'SELECT @xml.query(N''' + @xpath + '/text()'')'
    print @query
    EXECUTE(@query)
```

But it gives "Must declare the scalar variable "@xml" erorr

Answer (score 1):

The xmlns `xmlns:v1="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"` is a bit of a red herring - although it is declared, no nodes are actually defined in it. (Possibly unintended?)

You can use namespaces with XQuery with [`WITH NAMESPACES`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx), which will allow you to avoid using the agnostic `local-name()`:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soapenv,
'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' AS v1)
SELECT
  Nodes.node.value('(first)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS FirstName,
  Nodes.node.value('(last)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS LastName
FROM
  @xml.nodes('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/genRetrieve/checkRetrieve/party/user')
    AS Nodes(node);
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/31408)

**Edit**
Apologies, I missed the point you wanted to do this dynamically:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) =
N'WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
''http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'' AS soapenv,
''http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'' AS v1)
SELECT
  Nodes.node.value(''(' + @xpath + ')[1]'', ''varchar(50)'') AS FirstName
FROM
  @xml.nodes(''.'') AS Nodes(node)';    
exec sp_executesql @query, N'@xml xml', @xml = @xml;
```

[Updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/31410)

Comment: thanks for the answer - my problem is that i never know in advance what the namecpaces are going to be for any given XML so i cannot hardcode the `WITH XMLNAMESPACES ...` to any hardcoded value. IS there a way to dynamically populate the `WITH XMLNAMESPACES ...` to  namespaces present in @xml?